# Python Pandas - Concat two data frames with different number of rows and columns

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, data-analysis

I have two data frames with different row numbers and columns. Both tables has few common columns including "Customer ID". Both tables look like this with a size of 11697 rows × 15 columns and 385839 rows × 6 columns respectively. Customer ID might be repeating in second table. I want to concat  both of the tables and want to merge similar columns using Customer ID. How can I do that with python PANDAS.
One table looks like this -

[image]

and the other one looks like this -
[image]

I am using below code -

```
 pd.concat([df1, df2], sort=False)
```

Just wanted to make sure that I am not losing any information ? How can I check if there are multiple entries with one ID and how can I combine it in one result ?

EDIT -

When I am using above code, here is before and after values of NA'S in the dataset - 
[image]

Can someone tell, where I went wrong ?

Comment: Read the documentation for [pd.concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html)

Comment: concat is mainly used for stacking one dataframe on top of another

Answer (score 4):

I believe that `DataFrame.merge` would work in this case:

```
# use how='outer' to preserve all information from both DataFrames
df1.merge(df2, how='outer', on='customer_id')
```

`DataFrame.join` could also work if both DataFrames had their indexes set to `customer_id` (it is also simpler):

```
df1 = df1.set_index('customer_id')
df2 = df2.set_index('customer_id')
df1.join(df2, how='outer')
```

- [Documentation for `DataFrame.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)
- [Documentation for `DataFrame.join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html)

Comment: Second code suggestion - This code gives me an error - ValueError: columns overlap but no suffix specified: Index([u'state', u'timezone'], dtype='object')

Comment: Oh, okay... It's because both tables have columns named `state` and `timezone`. You will need to specify a suffix, so they become something along the lines of `state_suffix_left` and `state_suffix_right` in the resulting DataFrame. Check the documentation for the `join` method, the parameters `lsuffix` and `rsuffix`.

Comment: After setting the index of `df1` and `df2`, try calling `df1.join(df2, how='outer', lsuffix='_left', rsuffix='_right')`. I believe it will work.

Answer (score 0):

pd.concat will do the trick here,just set axis to 1 to concatenate on the second axis(columns), you should set the index to customer_id for both data frames first

```
import pandas as pd
pd.concat([df1.set_index('customer_id'), df2.set_index('customer_id')], axis = 1)
```

if you want to omit the rows with empty values as a result of your concatenaton, use dropna:

```
pd.concat([df1.set_index('customer_id'), df2.set_index('customer_id')], axis = 1).dropna()
```

Comment: This solution is giving me NA values for most of the data (38000 out of 39000 rows. If I drop the NA's, I am getting 0 rows.

Comment: concat will return nan values for any missing values, are your customer ids the same for both data frames?

Comment: I am not sure about customer ids because in one frame I have 11000 ids and in another data frame I have 39000 ids (observations)

Comment: in that case, how can you merge columns when the ids are different

Comment: sorry about this, I just checked. All id's are unique in both of the data frames.